# React js state update issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I updated state using to state method but one code does return undefined while another work correct can some help me explain what I am doing wrong

```
 const { title, fimg_url, content } = responseJson;
 this.setState({ title, fimg_url, content });
 this.setState({ data: responseJson });
```

in render this.state.data.title.rendered return undefined warning while title.rendered return correct api data

Comment: Are you using the correct variable names? Please check again to make sure you are using `this.state.data.title.rendered` and in the other case its `this.state.title.rendered`

Answer (score 2):

Each `setState` call results in a different state, you may want to use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on `responseJson.data` like so: `this.setState({ ...responseJson.data });`

```
// Each value reprensets an entry
this.setState({ title, fimg_url, content });
// state = { title: 'value', fimg_url: 'value', content: 'value' };


// responseJson is a value of `data` key
this.setState({ data: responseJson });
// state = { data: { title: 'value', fimg_url: 'value', content: 'value' }

// You may want to use:
this.setState({ ...responseJson.data });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your comparison is between `title.rendered` not this.state.title.rendered and `this.state.data.title.rendered`
then I think the reason is that the setState is asynchronous and maybe before the value of data is put on the state you are calling it already in some point inside render hence it's not yet available but as for title.rendered it's just a constant that is sitting there and waiting to be used. You can how ever make sure this works by doing a check ie if you did not expect just an answer then you can do something like

```
this.state.data && this.state.data.title.rendered
```